# Geometric Series function in Scheme language

Tags: scheme, racket

Im trying to learn scheme and Im having trouble with the arithmetic in the Scheme syntax.

Would anyone be able to write out a function in Scheme that represents the Geometric Series?

Answer (score 2):

You have `expt`, which is Scheme power procedure. `(expt 2 8) ; ==> 256` and you have `*` that does multiplication. eg. `(* 2 3) ; ==> 6`. From that you should be able to make a procedure that takes a `n` and produce the nth number in a specific geometric series.

You can also produce a list with the n first if you instead of using `expt` just muliply in a named let, basically doing the `expt` one step at a time and accumulate the values in a list. Here is an example of a procedure that makes a list of numbers:

```
(define (range from to)
  (let loop ((n to) (acc '())
    (if (< n from)
        acc
        (loop (- 1 n) (cons n acc)))))

(range 3 10) ; ==> (3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
```

Notice I'm doing them in reverse. If I cannot do it in reverse I would in the base case do `(reverse acc)` to get the right order as lists are always made from end to beginning. Good luck with your series.

Answer (score 1):

`range` behaves exactly like Python's range.

```
(define (range from (below '()) (step 1) (acc '()))
  (cond ((null? below) (range 0 from step))
        ((> (+ from step) below) (reverse acc))
        (else (range (+ from step) below step (cons from acc)))))
```

Python's range can take only one argument (the upper limit).

If you take `from` and `below` as required arguments, the definition is shorter:

```
(define (range from below (step 1) (acc '()))
  (cond ((> (+ from step) below) (reverse acc))
        (else (range (+ from step) below step (cons from acc)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer, in Racket, that you probably cannot submit as homework.

```
(define/contract (geometric-series x n)
  ;; Return a list of x^k for k from 0 to n (inclusive).
  ;; This will be questionable if x is not exact.
  (-> number? natural-number/c (listof number?))
  (let gsl ((m n)
            (c (expt x n))
            (a '()))
    (if (zero? m)
        (cons 1 a)
        (gsl (- m 1)
             (/ c x)
             (cons c a)))))
```

Comment: Typed racket <3

Comment: @Sylwester that's not Typed Racket